# On python, how to check the amount of times a letter is in a word (list)

Tags: python

So I have a stored word. And the user is invited to check if a letter of their choice is in this word. My code for this is the following

```
storedword = "abcdeef"
word = list(germ)
print (word)
merge = input("letter please")

print ("your letter is", merge)

counter = int(0)
letterchecker = int(0)
listlength = len(word)
while counter < listlength and merge != word[counter]:
    counter +=1

if counter <listlength:
    print ("found")

else:
    print ("not found")
```

How can I alter this code to check how many times the user letter is in this word? I can only use if's and while loops and not using .count

Comment: Your current code doesn't work, but you are already trying to count occurrences so just fix what you've got.

Comment: This feels a little bit too much of a school assignment. We're not here to do your homework but to help you out when you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
len([w for w in word if w == merge])
```

is short for

```
x = []
for w in word:
    if w == merge:
        x.append(w)
len(x)
```

Similar approach with while loop:

```
i = x = 0
while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == merge:
        x += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: What does for w in word mean?

Comment: OP initially said only while loops and ifs.

Comment: It's a way of iterating through the string. `for w in word` means that we'll loop through the list of letters in the string `word` one by one and assign it to the variable `w`. If `word` is `hello`, `w` will be `h` in the first run, `e` in the second etc until the last when it's `o`.

Comment: is the for w in word like another method?

Comment: @GarrettR fair enough, didn't think of it, just the not using `.count` part.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

storedword = "abcdeef"

wordcounter = Counter(list(storedword))

merge = input("letter please ")

print("your letter is %s" % merge)
print('It occurs %d times' % wordcounter[merge])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
letter_count = 0
while counter < len(word);
    if word[counter] == merge:
         letter_count +=1
    counter +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
counter = 0
for c in word:
    if c == merge:
        counter += 1
```

If you can't use for, use:

```
counter = 0
ind = 0
while ind < len(word):
    if word[ind] == merge:
        counter += 1
    ind +=1
```